# Cannot get JSON entries as an array

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have an Angular Frontend and Springboot Backend (with mysql database). I want to get entries of the database as an array, that I can display them on the frontend. I'm really new to this and need some help.

This are the JSON entries:

```
[{"id":1,"grund":"fehlendes Material"},
{"id":2,"grund":"gebrochenes Werkzeug"},
{"id":3,"grund":"verschlissenes Werkzeug"},
{"id":4,"grund":"defekte Maschine/Magazin"},
{"id":5,"grund":"fehlende Betriebsmittel"},
{"id":6,"grund":"fehlendes Personal"},
{"id":7,"grund":"Zeichnungsproblem"},
{"id":8,"grund":"fehlendes Programm"}]
```

I just need the "grund" entries, I want to list them all in a select-option menu.

This is my service, where I get the json entries form the database:

```
  getGruendeStillstand(): Observable<Vorgang[]> {
    return this.http.get<Vorgang[]>(`${environment.baseURL}/gruende-stillstand/all`);
  }
```

I call this in the component.ts:

```
export class GrundDialogComponent implements OnInit{

  grund: string;
  data: any;
  size: number = this.data.length;

  constructor(private vorgangService: VorgangService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<GrundDialogComponent>, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getGruendeStillstand();

  }

  getGruendeStillstand() {
    this.vorgangService.getGruendeStillstand().subscribe(res => {
      this.data = res;

      this.grund = this.data.grund;

      console.log(this.data);

    });
  }
```

And later I want to display just the "grund" from this database-table in a select-option:

```html
<div [formGroup]="form" class="gruende">
    <select [(ngModel)]="grund" formControlName="grund" size="{{size}}">
      <option *ngFor="let item of data" [ngValue]="item">{{item}}</option> 
    </select>
</div>
```

Unfortunately I only get an error and I don't even get the array itself (I tried just for testing purposes with a console.log to display the array)

Comment: What are the errors that you get. See my answer below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your service gives you an array of `Vorgang`, wich is of type

```
{'id': number, 'grund': string}
```

So if you want to have an array of only `grund` you can:

```
this.grund = this.data.map(vorgang => vorgang.grund);
```

And then iterate over `this.grund` to fill your select-option.

Comment: This worked for  me, thanks a lot. I configured the html for this by myself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **`form`** as below and **`item.grund`** to show options in **`select`** as follows.

```
<div class="gruende">
    <form [formGroup]="form">
        <select [(ngModel)]="grund" formControlName="grund" size="{{size}}">
           <option *ngFor="let item of data" [ngValue]="item">{{item.grund}}</option> 
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

**[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-56889074?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**